# How can I parse a non-ISO8601 timestamp to format as ISO8601 in XSLT?

Tags: parsing, xslt, datetime

If I have a document in XSLT containing timestamps in some known format, how can I parse these timestamps in the template so that I can then format them in say ISO8601?

Example formats:

- UNIX epoch millis
- yyMMddHHmmssZ (Using Java SimpleDateFormat format string)

Is there a difference in how to do this in XSLT 1.0 vs. 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XSLT 2.0 you have date and dateTime data types to compute dates, for instance to convert a UNIX epoch milliseconds value since 1970 to dateTime see http://p2p.wrox.com/xslt/79802-convert-format-unix-timestamp.html, you can do e.g. `xs:dateTime('1970-01-01T00:00:00') + $N * xs:dayTimeDuration('PT0.001S')`. Then you can format such a `dateTime` with the function `format-dateTime` http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#format-date.